# How to select DISTINCT records based on multiple columns and without considering their order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently working on a SQL Server database and I would need a query that returns pairs of customers with the same city from a table that has this structure

```
Customer(ID, Name, Surname, City)
```

and this sample data

```
Name       | Surname   | City
-----------+-----------+-----------
Foo        | Foo       | New York
-----------+-----------+-----------
Bar        | Bar       | New York
-----------+-----------+-----------
Alice      | A         | London
-----------+-----------+-----------
Bob        | B         | London
```

I have tried defining a query that joins the Customer table itself

```
SELECT C1.Name + ' ' + C1.Surname CustomerA, C2.Name + ' ' + C2.Surname CustomerB, C1.City
FROM Customer C1 JOIN Customer C2 
     ON C1.City = C2.City
WHERE CustomerA <> CustomerB
```

but it gives me a table that looks like this

```
CustomerA  | CustomerB | City
-----------+-----------+-----------
Foo Foo    | Bar Bar   | New York
-----------+-----------+-----------
Bar Bar    | Foo Foo   | New York
-----------+-----------+-----------
Alice A    | Bob B     | London
-----------+-----------+-----------
Bob B      | Alice A   | London
```

with duplicated rows but with swapped customers.

My question is how would I have to do to select those rows once (e.g. for the first two results, it would be great only the first or the second row).

This would be an example of the expected result

```
CustomerA  | CustomerB | City
-----------+-----------+-----------
Foo Foo    | Bar Bar   | New York
-----------+-----------+-----------
Alice A    | Bob B     | London
```

Comment: It would really help if you can provide some sample data. And when you find a "match" which row do you want returned?

Comment: Sure, I'll update the question. Thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are more than two customers from the same city with different names?

Comment: All possible combinations would be fine

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. You said you want only one of the pairs. Add a third customer to one of your cities and what should the output be? I think maybe you have simplified the question so much it is hard to understand your actual requirements.

Comment: Yes, I said I only want one of the pairs but if they have the same customers but swapped. If we add a third customer to one city, the resulting combinations would include (A, B), (B, C), (C, A) but not, for example, (B, A), because we already have it above (is equivalent to (A, B))

Comment: Nope that doesn't make sense.  Foo Foo <> Bar Bar. But if you also smith smith it would be a third customer in the same city. In that case why would Foo and Bar be "swapped" but smith wouldn't?

Comment: Ok, maybe I can't explain exactly what I mean. I take a step back. I need to build a table with all the pairs of customers that are in the same city. How would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you are looking for but it seems over simplified to your actual problem. Your query you posted was incredibly close to working. You can't reference columns by their alias in the where predicates so you will need to use the string concatenation you had in your column. Then you can simply change the <> to either > or < so you only get one match. This example should work for your problem as I understand it.

```
declare @Customer table
(
    CustID int identity
    , Name varchar(10)
    , Surname varchar(10)
    , City varchar(10)
)

insert @Customer
select 'Foo', 'Foo', 'New York' union all
select 'Bar', 'Bar', 'New York' union all
select 'Smith', 'Smith', 'New York' union all
select 'Alice', 'A', 'London' union all
select 'Bob', 'B', 'London'

SELECT CustomerA = C1.Name + ' ' + C1.Surname
    , CustomerB = C2.Name + ' ' + C2.Surname
    , C1.City
FROM @Customer C1 
JOIN @Customer C2 ON C1.City = C2.City
where C1.Name + ' ' + C1.Surname > C2.Name + ' ' + C2.Surname
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` and `group by` clause for this query

```
select concat(C1.Name," ",C1.surname) as CustomerA, concat(C2.Name," ",C2.surname) CustomerB,C1.city 
from customer C1 
left join customer C2 
on C1.city=C2.city  and C1.name<>C2.name
group by C1.city;
```